# Populating an UI Element with Excel Rows in Power Automate Desktop

Tags: excel, loops, user-interface, power-automate

I've been trying to develop this flow that creates a workbook and pastes in cell A1 any order number that the user has stored in the clipboard, then, PAD takes each cell and pastes it on a UI element in a website, which is a table.

I currently have an issue with the loops, since I'm trying to make this as less hard coded as possible, I need to make a loop that iterates through each order in the excel workbook and populates each UI element in the website. (Excel 1,1 goes to UI 1,1 ; Excel 2,1 goes to UI 2,1 ; and so and on depending on the amount of orders) *I only have 1 column in each data set.

Currently, the loop does iterate through 1 order and populates correctly in the website, however, when I add second order, the loop iterates twice as it should, but populates UI 1,1 and 2,1 with the first order, and then overwrites UI 1,1 and 2,1 with the second order. I was expecting my loop to populate UI 1,1 with the first order and then UI 2,1 with the second one.

[This is my flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhkBg.png)

I'm basically new at PAD and very stuck at this point.

Thanks for any help provided :)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct to loop through each row in your ExcelData, but you should not loop through your UI text fields, you should just assign which single UI text field you want to populate each time you loop.

Create a new variable that will keep track of how many times you have run through the loop. This will correspond to which row of ExcelData you are on, and which UI text field you want to populate.

See below the Set variable and Increase variable steps I have added. I just used a Display Message instead of your Populate text field, you will have to adapt it to your website.

[image]